# Retry in rxJava

Tags: java, unit-testing, rx-java, reactive-programming

I want to test the retry in the code:

```
public Observable<Foo> getFoo() {
        return barService.getBar()
                .retry(3)
                .map(barToFoo);
}
```

and the unit test:

```
//given
barService = Mockito.mock(BarService.class)
PublishSubject<Bar> barSubject= PublishSubject.create();
when(barService.getBar()).thenReturn(barSubject);

TestSubscriber<Foo> fooProbe= new TestSubscriber<>();
getFoo().subscribe(fooProbe);

//when
barSubject.onError(new RuntimeException("bar exception"));
barSubject.onNext(new Bar())

//then
fooProbe.assertNoErrors();
fooProbe.assertValue(new Bar());
```

fails with `java.lang.AssertionError: Unexpected onError events: 1`

Comment: Calling `onError` or `onCompleted` brings the `Subject`s into a terminal state and no further events are accepted/relayed.

Comment: Understood. So what would be the correct approach?

Comment: If you want to test your retry with an error scenario, you have to think in which situation you code could cause onError and exploit it on your test. But as they telling you, calling onError or OnComplete will make the subject to finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `onError` or `onCompleted` brings the `Subject`s into a terminal state and no further events are accepted/relayed.

Generally, you can't do retry with `Subject`s but you can try with `fromCallable` and a counter:

```
AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();
Observable<Bar> o = Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
    if (count.incrementAndGet() >= 3) {
        return new Bar();
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("bar exception");
});

when(barService.getBar()).thenReturn(o);
```